# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am trying to learn python and trying to write a simple script.  There seems to be a problem with using a raw_input created variable.  I am sure it's simple, but I just don't have the background yet to figure this one out. Here is what I've tried and what works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import hashlib

v = raw_input("Enter your value: ")
print "Which hash algorithm do you want to use?"
# This fails
a = raw_input("md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512: ")
h = hashlib.a(v)
h.hexdigest()

# This works

v = "password"
h = hashlib.md5(v)
h.hexdigest()
```

Comment: replace `hashlib.a` with `getattr(hashlib, a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is just storing a variable with a string value. `hashlib.a()` is just trying to call a method called `a` in the hashlib module (which doesnt exist). Try instead using

```
h = haslib.new(a)
h.update(v)
h.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hashes = ("md5", "sha1", "sha224", "sha256", "sha384", "sha512")

chosen_hash = None

while not chosen_hash:
    try_hash = raw_input("%s: " % (",".join(hashes))
    if try_hash in hashes:
        chosen_hash = try_hash

hash_func = getattr(hashlib, chosen_hash)()
hash_func.update(v)
```

As @gos1 suggested, you might use `hashlib.new(chosen_hash)` instead.

The nice thing is this will guard against someone entering `foo` as their choice and having your program blow up.

Comment: Use a set literal `{"md5", "sha1", ...}` and this will be perfect.

Comment: @sberry I agree. In a real-world application, never let a user enter raw input that might be evaluated, unless you're 100% sure that such evaluation won't break up your program, or worse...

Comment: Famous last words "unless you are 100% sure"